# Check if another element is checked inside angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tags, angular-material

Say I have the following html:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-checkbox>Are you foreign?</md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <md-checkbox> local </md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <md-checkbox> foreign </md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>
```

I want to show local or foreign checkbox depending on the first checkbox, without using js at all.

I thought on something with `ng-if=""` but have no idea at all if this can be done without accessing js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `md-checkbox` has a [variety of attributes](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox) you can add to check for such changes

Comment: you could use `ng-checked="foreign"` / `ng-checked="!foreign"` which you can then use the first checkbox to set to true or false. See example here: [Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Comment: Thankyou @G.Clarke, quite easier than thought.

Answer (score 0):

Following @G. Clarke comment, I did the following:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-checkbox ng-model="foreign">Are you foreign?</md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>

<md-input-container ng-if="!foreign">
    <md-checkbox> local </md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>

<md-input-container ng-if="foreign">
    <md-checkbox> foreign </md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>
```

Hope it helps.